# How to use cdk cross-account access with OIDC and EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, amazon-eks

Followed this link: [Enabling cross-account access to Amazon EKS cluster resources](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/enabling-cross-account-access-to-amazon-eks-cluster-resources/)
I can make a pod in an Amazon EKS cluster hosted in `ci account` interact and manage the AWS resources in a `target account`.
This is the aws config file:

```
[profile ci-env]
role_arn = arn:aws-cn:iam::CICD_ACCOUNT:role/eksctl-jenkins-cicd-demo-addon-iamserviceacc-Role1-1AQZO394370HE
web_identity_token_file = /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
region = cn-north-1

[profile target-env]
role_arn = arn:aws-cn:iam::TARGET_ACCOUNT:role/target-account-iam-role
source_profile = ci-env
role_session_name = xactarget
region = cn-north-1
```

When I run `aws s3 ls --profile target-env`, it worked and listed the s3 buckets in my `target account`.

Then, I want to deploy a [cdk app](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/hello_world.html) on `ci account` which can create s3 bucket on `target account`.
But When I run `cdk deploy --profile target-env`, it appeared:

```
Need to perform AWS calls for account TARGET_ACCOUNT, but no credentials have been configured.
```

I am very confused and don't know how to solve it.
I am a beginner of aws service, thanks advance for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [bootstrap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html) all of your (target) accounts to trust the CICD account.

Otherwise, you would have to create and manage the cross-account access by yourself.

- IAM Roles + Policies (in all accounts)
- S3 Bucket for artifacts + bucket policies (in CICD account)
- Key Management Service -> Customer Managed Key + Policies to allow the target accounts

You can spot here an example architecture, which is applying that:
[image]

If it's possible for you, you might switch to the [CDK Pipelines](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cdk-pipelines-continuous-delivery-for-aws-cdk-applications/).
In this guide, also the bootstrapping (incl. trusting) is being applied and every step/resource mentioned from above is being created and properly configured.
It has a few drawbacks as of now, but it's in developer preview and has a quite decent usability and makes your life a lot easier already.